# Max file size with resteasy and multipart/form-data request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, multipartform-data

How can I control the max file size and/or the max request size when using resteasy to handle a multipart/form-data request ?

My code looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/somerestresource")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response handleForm(@MultipartForm MyForm form) {
    ...
}
```

With a Servlet I can control stuff with the `@MultipartConfig` annotation.

So I'm thinking about bypassing resteasy and using `@Context` to inject a `HttpServletRequest` and having my servlet configured inside the web.xml but I'm unsure of the side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JAX-RS 2.0, you could use a ContainerRequestFilter bound to your upload method using a `@NameBinding` annotation. In this filter, you would look at the `content-length` request header and discard the request if the content length exceeds the maximum value you plan to accept (`requestContext.abortWith(...)`)

With JAX-RS 1.1 and RESTEasy, you could probably do the same thing using a PreProcessInterceptor (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html#PreProcessInterceptors) and follow a logic logic similar to the one described above.

Comment: After days of searching, I guess it's the way to go ! I was looking for more "built-in" solutions but I can't find anything. Thanks !

Comment: Content-Length  is not the right way to get the file size, technically the header is optional, please see the response on the a similar request here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811675/2517413

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Xavier, you can also get the `content-length` header from an injected `@Context HttpServletRequest`. Furthermore, this is not enough, because the header may not be available (e.g. when chunking is used for the POST body). You then have two options: let the call fail, because you don't know the length of the stream, or resort to using, e.g., `BoundedInputStream` to read the body of the upload part of the request.

Minor detail: the `content-length` header is usually sent along with the main request, and not with each part of the multipart data. It therefore does not accurately represent the size of the upload.