# Wildfly 9: Undertow setup by programming [max-post-size] rather than modifying standalone.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, undertow, programmatic-config

I need to increase the max-post-size of my undertow configuration, because I got the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760 
at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.checkMaxSize(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:168)
```

and I need post requests with larger payloads.

However, I know that I could adapt `standalone.xml`, but I was not able to figure successfully out, how I can do this by programming or at least in web.xml (I need to be able to put the change in the build artifact rather than in the server configuration).

**Edit**:
I use the post requests with jax-rs `@Post` methods. If it is possible to e.g. annotate a payload size per request, it would also be OK, since there are only few requests needing higher payload size enabled.

Can anybody point my to what I can do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I need to be able to put the change in the build artifact rather than in the server configuration)` - why is that? You can script this change using the jboss-cli tool.

Comment: Because this is the preferred way to deal with portable applications hosted in the cloud. This is an important 'best practise'.

Comment: I'd be interested to know where you heard this. How are you deploying your application?

Comment: You might also consider using WildFly Swarm for this purpose. This bundles your application, the bits of WIldFly that you use and it's configuration into a single executable jar file.

Comment: @Steve C: You go off topic. The question is clear and makes sence. I need a solution for this scenario, if there is one; nothing else.

Comment: I don't think he's that off topic. You wanted a way to define the `max-post-size` via your application. WildFly Swarm can do this.

Comment: I cannot use Swarm because the infrastructure is given.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with an annotation. You'd have to change the `max-post-size` attribute on the [listener](https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/10.0.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html). A change to the listener requires a reload which is why it's not possible from an annotation.

With CLI on the default `http-listener` the command would be:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=max-post-size, value=20971520)
```

Comment: Is there no way to setup the listener of the servlet in the web.xml? What I have found is how to setup size of multipart bodies etc. but not max-post-size.

Comment: Not that I know of since it's JAX-RS. If it was a servlet you can use the `javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig` annotation. Maybe something like this would work though http://stackoverflow.com/a/20883976.

Answer (score 0):

Open admin console 
click configuration
click subsystem
click on web/http- undertow
click on http
HTTP-server-> defual-server
edit max-post-size

Comment: The question was how to do it by programming, not by setting up wildfly specific configuration. -1